# table parsing , copy image , graph etc from one docx to new docx - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, docx, python-docx

pydocx

I am wondering is there a way to save pic, tables etc from one docx to a new docx using python ? I am using python-docx to read a docx and doing some operations on the text by paragraph and copying it to a new docs but in this activity , any table or pic is getting missed . Seems the code itself does not read it . I want the pic, graphs , columns etc at their place . Is it possible ? Please help me  on this.

```
import docx 
doc = docx.Document('demo.docx')
doc1 = docx.Document()
l =len(doc.paragraphs)
for i in range(l):
    d = doc.paragraphs[i].text
    some_op = d.upper() #taking .upper as an example but doing something else here 
    doc1.add_paragraph(some_op.text)
doc1.save('Paragraphs.docx')
```

The newly created Paragraphs.docs is missing images, tables etc from the place.

Answer (score 0):

you are using doc.paragraphs which just returns all the paragraphs in the document.
To access tables and images you need to use Table and inline_shape objects. You can find them here in the official documentation.

[Tabels](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html)

[Shapes and images](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape.html)